# Issue in selecting sub menu in firefox using webdriver java

Tags: firefox, webdriver

32

The following code i am using to hover and click

```
 Actions actions = new Actions(driver)
 WebElement Mainmenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[6]/a"))
 WebElement Submenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[6]/ul/li[1]/a"));
 WebElement Childsubmenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[6]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a"));
      actions.moveToElement(Mainmenu).moveToElement(Submenu).moveToElement(Childsubmenu).click().build().perform();
```

It works perfectly fine in Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox 22.

Comment: Just not working the first step were it hovers is not workin i am using selenium 2.32

Comment: [CHANGELOG](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG#49) told me Selenium 2.32 supports only Firefox 20 or under. Could you please try downgrade to Firefox 20? Or upgrade Selenium to 2.33.0

Comment: Selenium 2.33.0 doesn't support FF 22 too as I know.

Comment: I tried the new selenium as well as tried older firefox didn't work any other suggestions

Comment: May be you need to use some other approach. `moveToElement` is not stable function.

Comment: Agree with @Evgeniy. I use moveToElement only in special cases, such as analytics testing

Comment: I am new to this and have no idea which other options should i use